# Inelastica Pakage

Tags: density-functional-theory, siesta, density-of-states, charge-density

I'm use the [Inelastica package](https://tfrederiksen.github.io/inelastica/docs/latest/api-gen/Inelastica.html) to compute MPSH states and analyze the  (HOMO/LUMO). For that, I run the [Eigenchannels](https://tfrederiksen.github.io/inelastica/docs/latest/api-gen/Inelastica.EigenChannels.html#scripting) command with :
`Eigenchannels -f /*fdf -M 1 -w cube MPSH/`

This results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/EigenChannels", line 12, in <module>
    Module.main(options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Inelastica/EigenChannels.py", line 134, in main
    options.DeviceAtoms[1]+L,lasto)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Inelastica/SiestaIO.py", line 1326, in BuildBasis
    ions[int(CSL[i][0])] = ReadIonNCFile(head+'/%s.ion.nc'%CSL[i][2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Inelastica/SiestaIO.py", line 1275, in ReadIonNCFile
    file = NC4.Dataset(filename,'r')
  File "netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1848, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__ (netCDF4/_netCDF4.c:13983)
IOError: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Try to post the error information inside a code block, please.

Comment: Did you consider [raising an issue](https://github.com/tfrederiksen/inelastica/issues) on the packages Github page? Its possible this is a bug, either in the code itself or with the installation process.

Comment: The error looks like the files (in netCDF format) are missing. Did you compile SIESTA with netCDF4?

Comment: Seems like you need to load netCDF4 before compiling.

Comment: Thank you all it work ^^

Comment: @AH Since it works, can you write an answer? It will be useful for future users.

Comment: Be sure that all the library of Inelastica packages are installed correctly